# How to build a dropdown in tkinter that executes an operation to send a message based on the option selected

Tags: python, tkinter

So I'm building a gui to send messages to different chat rooms. At the moment, the code is built to send the message to all the chat rooms. But I want to add a dropdown menu to select chat rooms based on region so that the message will go to specific rooms based on selection.

The chat rooms look like this:

| Chat Room Number | Region |
| --- | --- |
| Room 1 | Tokyo |
| Room 2 | London |
| Room 3 | London |
| Room 4 | New York |
| Room 5 | New York |
| Room 6 | Sydney |

So for example, a dropdown would allow me to choose a city (e.g. London) and then either allow me to select "All" for all rooms or a specific room like Room 2.

My code so far is this:

```
import json
import requests
import sys
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

import requests

url1 = 'room1.chatroom'
uri2 = 'room2.chatroom'
etc etc 

root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")
root.title(" Send Message ")


def take_input():
    message = inputtxt.get("1.0", "end-1c")
    print(message)
    def send_message():
        r1 = requests.post(url=uri1, json={"Content": message})
        r2 = requests.post(url=uri2, json={"Content": message})
    send_message()


l = Label(text="What message do you want to send?")
inputtxt = Text(root, height=10,
                width=25,
                bg="light yellow")
Display = Button(root, height=2,
                 width=20,
                 text="Send",
                 command = lambda:take_input())

l.pack()
inputtxt.pack()
Display.pack()
mainloop()
```

Comment: Sounds like what you want is the `ttk.OptionMenu` widget, which is essentially a dropdown. You can set a callback for when the user selects an option and then react accordingly. And FWIW, you don't need both `import tkinter as tk` and `from tkinter import *` - in general it's best to use `import tkinter as tk` and to avoid star imports. To use `ttk` you'll need `from tkinter import ttk`

Comment: Yeah it's the callback portion I'm struggling with. I know I can use an if statement to set up the selections and which rooms to send the message in but it's the callback that I'm having difficulty conceptualizing.

Answer (score 0):

> **EDITED:** Let me know if you wanted, for example, to send to "all rooms in a specific city" and not to "all rooms", and I'll update my question.

Not sure if this is what you want to do, but you can use a [Combobox](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Combobox) and use the `.get` method and use it like in the example below:

MRE:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

def send():
    where = combo.get()
    if where in rooms.keys(): # selected a city
        print('Sending to all rooms in %s...' %where)
        for url, _ in rooms[where]:
            print('Sent to url "%s"' %url)

    else: # selected a specific room
        print('Sending to specific room...')
        for city in rooms:
            for url, name in rooms[city]:
                if name == where:
                    print('Sent to url "%s"' %url)
    print()

rooms = {'Tokyo':    [('url0', 'Room 1')],
         'London':   [('url1', 'Room 2'),
                      ('url2', 'Room 3')],
         'New York': [('url3', 'Room 4'),
                      ('url4', 'Room 5')],
         'Sydney':   [('url5', 'Room 6')]}

possible = [r[1] for city in rooms for r in rooms[city]]+list(rooms.keys())

root = Tk()
Label(root, text='Enter message:').grid(columnspan=2)
input_text = Text(root, height=3, width=25)
input_text.grid(columnspan=2)

combo = Combobox(root, values=possible, state='readonly')
combo.set(possible[0])
combo.grid()

Button(root, text='Send to...', command=send).grid(row=2, column=1)
root.mainloop()
```

In this example, the rooms are stored in a dictionary with cities as keys and rooms as values, as a tuple with the url and the name.
This way, you can easily add a room or see in which city it is in.

A read-only `Combobox` (note that you need `tkinter.ttk` to use it, at least on Windows) stores all possible room names (`[r[1] for city in rooms for r in rooms[city]]`), followed by the different cities (`list(room.keys())`).

The `send()` function gets the value of the `Combobox`, then checks if it is a city. In this case, you just need to iterate through `rooms[selected city]` to get all the URLs to send to.

If the `Combobox` value is a room name, you need to iterate through each room in each country, then check if the name of these rooms is the same as the name of the selected room.

You can use IDs if you want to handle duplicates (rooms with the same name), but this shouldn't matter as I don't think you would need such a thing in a practical case.

Hope this edit helped you!

Comment: This looks great actually!
I didn't even know combobox exists until I read your comment and googled it.
but yes I actually meant to send the message to all rooms in a specific city.
So for example, if I click on London, the next dropdown should allow me to select either a specific room or all the rooms under London. 

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary to store the chatroom information and create two comboboxes for the cities and chatrooms:

```py
#import json
#import sys
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
#import requests

# dictionary for chatroom information
chatrooms = {
    "Tokyo": {
        "Room 1": "room1.chatroom",
    },
    "London": {
        "Room 2": "room2.chatroom",
        "Room 3": "room3.chatroom",
    },
    "New York": {
        "Room 4": "room4.chatroom",
        "Room 5": "room5.chatroom",
    },
    "Sydney": {
        "Room 6": "room6.chatroom",
    },
}
ALL = "All"

root = tk.Tk()
#root.geometry("300x300")
root.title(" Send Message ")

def on_city_selected(event):
    city = city_var.get()
    rooms = sorted(list(chatrooms[city].keys()))
    if len(rooms) > 1:
        rooms.insert(0, ALL)
    room_combo.config(values=rooms)
    room_var.set(rooms[0])

def take_input():
    message = inputtxt.get("1.0", "end-1c")
    city = city_var.get()
    if message and city:
        print(message)
        room = room_var.get()
        rooms = chatrooms[city] if room == ALL else {room: chatrooms[city][room]}
        for room, url in rooms.items():
            print(f"sending message to {url} ({city}: {room})")
            #r = requests.post(url=url1, json={"Content": message})
    else:
        print("Either no message input or no city selected")

cl = tk.Label(root, text="Select city:")
city_var = tk.StringVar()
cities = sorted(list(chatrooms.keys()))
city_combo = ttk.Combobox(root, textvariable=city_var, values=cities, state="readonly")
city_combo.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", on_city_selected)

rl = tk.Label(root, text="Select room:")
room_var = tk.StringVar()
room_combo = ttk.Combobox(root, textvariable=room_var, state="readonly")

l = tk.Label(root, text="What message do you want to send?")
inputtxt = tk.Text(root, height=10, width=25, bg="light yellow")
Display = tk.Button(root, height=2, width=20, text="Send", command=take_input)

cl.pack(anchor="w")
city_combo.pack(anchor="w")
rl.pack(anchor="w")
room_combo.pack(anchor="w")
l.pack(anchor="w")
inputtxt.pack()
Display.pack(anchor="e")

tk.mainloop()
```